# Javascript multi-step form in Rails 4 - Can't submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

My Rails form works fine before I implement a javascript solution to a multi-step form found here. http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Creating-A-Modern-Multi-Step-Form-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

It works fine, but it won't submit/store the data in the end. Any suggestions? Here's the .form.html.erb file.

```js
$(function() {

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
step: function(now, mx) {
//as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
//1. scale current_fs down to 80%
scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
//2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
left = (now * 50)+"%";
//3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
opacity = 1 - now;
current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
}, 
duration: 800, 
complete: function(){
current_fs.hide();
animating = false;
}, 
//this comes from the custom easing plugin
easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

//de-activate current step on progressbar
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

//show the previous fieldset
previous_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
step: function(now, mx) {
//as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
//1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
//2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
//3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
opacity = 1 - now;
current_fs.css({'left': left});
previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
}, 
duration: 800, 
complete: function(){
current_fs.hide();
animating = false;
}, 
//this comes from the custom easing plugin
easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
return false;
})

});
```

```css
CSS File
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
.form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@journey,  :remote=> true) do |f| %>
<% if @journey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@journey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this journey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @journey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
    <h2>STEP 1: Add an image for the journey</h2>

      <%= f.file_field :image, class: "btn btn-primary" %><br>
      <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or paste image URL here" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
     <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h2>STEP 2: Describe the journey</h2>
        <%= f.label :name, "1. Add a catchy name to make your journey stand out." %>
        <%= f.text_area :name, class: "form-control" %>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :description, "2. Add 2-3 tags to describe your journey (e.g., hungry, hipster, nighttime)" %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
    <h2>STEP 3: Add Clues</h2>
        <%= f.fields_for :clues do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'clue_fields', f:builder %>
        <% end %>
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Another Clue", f, :clues, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
     <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
      <h2>STEP 4: Rate the difficulty from 1-5</h2>
        <%= f.number_field :difficulty, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

          <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <%= f.submit %>

      </fieldset>


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point in the js code:

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
  return false;
})
```

You need to implement your submit functionality. Something along the lines of (using coffeescript):

```
jqxhr = $.post(
  url
  (data, textStatus, jqXHR) -> 
    console.log 'i guess it worked'
)
jqxhr.fail ->
  console.log jqxhr.responseText
```

Naturally, this assumes you have set the `url` value.

So, your code would end up looking something like this (again, in coffeescript... you'll have to convert back to regular js):

```
$(".submit").click ->
  jqxhr = $.post(
    url
    (data, textStatus, jqXHR) -> 
      console.log 'i guess it worked'
  )
  jqxhr.fail ->
    console.log jqxhr.responseText
```

As to how the set the URL, in your non-js version, what URL do you set on the submit button?

Comment: Thanks! I don't have much background in this. 2 follow-ups:

1. Should this code replace the $(".submit") code? 
2. Do you have any idea what to se tthe URL value as in a Rails app?